# Syncing CSS Animation

Tags: html, css

I have a color changing CSS animation for my button. I decided to make it solid when hovered over. Though the code works and the color still changes, the animation resets each time when I hover over it. Is there a way to make the color animation for the hover state to be the same color as the non-hover state was prior to the action (so when non-hover is green, it is still green when hovered over).

http://codepen.io/Dingerzat/pen/mRdObJ

```css
/* CSS */

.enquire_button {
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #f35626;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #f35626;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s;
  -o-transition: color .4s;
  transition: color .4s;
  -webkit-animation: hue 60s linear;
  -o-animation: hue 60s linear;
  animation: hue 60s linear;
  text-align: center;
}
.enquire_button:hover {
  background-color: #f35626;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s;
  -o-transition: color .4s;
  transition: color .4s;
  -webkit-animation: hue 60s linear;
  -o-animation: hue 60s linear;
  animation: hue 60s linear;
}
.color_button {
  animation-name: color_change;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
.color_button:hover {
  animation-name: color_change2;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes color_change2 {
  0% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes color_change2 {
  0% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes color_change2 {
  0% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes color_change2 {
  0% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
@keyframes color_change2 {
  0% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="enquire_button color_button">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Try to refactor the function "color_change" to change the color of the background, not the border: use a span with transparent background, set to white on hover, or 'vice versa'...

Comment: I will give this a try, this seems like it could be the best way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this is the only way: use a span, or a double element, like the answes of the others member you suggested, See the @Kieran McClung demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve, it requires extra markup though. I've tried to keep your code as intact as possible but have stripped it down for the example. Full required code attached in [codepen](http://codepen.io/raptorkraine/pen/qRBjXR).

HTML

```
<button class="enquire_button color_button">
  <span class="button_text">Click here</span>
</button>
```

CSS

```
.enquire_button {
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color_change;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #f35626;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #f35626;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  min-height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color .4s;
  width: 7em;  
}

.enquire_button:before {
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: background-color .4s;
  width: 100%;
}

.enquire_button:hover .button_text {
  color: #fff;
}

.enquire_button:hover:before {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.button_text {
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes color_change {
  0% {
    background-color: #da6e16;
    color: #da6e16;
    border: 4px solid #da6e16;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: #82da16;
    color: #82da16;
    border: 4px solid #82da16;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #16dad0;
    color: #16dad0;
    border: 4px solid #16dad0;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: #d41a82;
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #d41a82;
    color: #d41a82;
    border: 4px solid #d41a82;
  }
}
```

Comment: The example code works perfectly. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think what this can do through double button))

```
<div class="btn">
    <button>Button #1</button>
    <button>Button #2</button>
</div>
```

Button #1 - animation infinite.

Button #2 - white background

```
.bnt button + button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `:after` pseudoelement

```css
/* Color changing button */

.enquire_button {
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.color_button {
  animation: color_change 10s infinite alternate;
}
.color_button:after {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  content: "Click here";
}
.color_button:hover {
  background-color: currentcolor;
}
.color_button:hover:after {
  color: #fff;
}

@keyframes color_change {
  0% { color: #da6e16; }
  25% { color: #82da16; }
  50% { color: #16dad0; }
  75% { color: #d41a82; }
  100% { color: #d41a82; }
}
```

```html
<button class="enquire_button color_button"></button>
```

2. Using `hue-rotate` CSS filter

```css
/* Color changing button */

.enquire_button {
  min-height: 2em;
  width: 7em;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.color_button {
  color: #da6e16;
  animation: color_change 10s infinite alternate;
}
.color_button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da6e16;
  border-color: #da6e16;
}

@keyframes color_change {
  0% { filter: hue-rotate(0deg); }
  100% { filter: hue-rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<button class="enquire_button color_button">
  Click here
</button>
```